# Jquery #id focus() display none id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, hidden

I'm using Jquery to focus an input at page load, this input is duplicated in two divs, but one is hidden with "display:none".
If I change the id of the hidden one, it works, so I guess "display:none" does not exclude the input.
What do you suggest? Thank you!!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  focusMainEntry();
});

function focusMainEntry() {
  $('#codbar').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputsPedido" style="display:none;">
  <form action="insert_stock.php" method="post" name="formulario_carga" class="form-signin">
    ...
    <input type="text" id="codbar" name="codbar" class="form-control" placeholder="Código de barra" style='width:180px;' />...
  </form>
</div>
<div id="inputsPedidoVencimientoLote">
  <form action="insert_stockTEST.php" method="post" name="formulario_carga" class="form-signin">
    ...
    <input type="text" id="codbar" name="codbar" class="form-control" placeholder="Código de barra" style='width:180px;' />...
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: id should be unique.thats why its called id.  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*id* should be unique. When you use `$('#codbar').focus();` to focus the element with id `codbar`, the first element with the id is selected(which is hidden). Use it as class.

Use `autofocus` attribute.

```html
<input type="text" id="codbar" name="codbar" placeholder="Código de barra" autofocus />
```